# Determining continuity and differentiability

Tags: functions, continuity

Is this function continuous and differentiable?

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
1-x & x<1 \\
x^2-2x+1 & x\:\ge 1
\end{array}\right.$$

For continuity, I did $$\lim_{x\to 1^+\:}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 1^-\:}f(x) = f(1)$$ and they all equal 0. So that means it is continuous.

Now, from what I know, if a function is continuous and if $$\lim_{x\to 1^+\:}f'(x) = \lim_{x\to 1^-\:}f'(x) = constant$$
then the function is also differentiable.

So, I got, $$\lim_{x\to 1^+\:}f'(x)=0$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 1^-\:}f'(x)=-1$$

And they're not equal! Which means that the function isn't differentiable at $x = 1$ ?

Also, what if the function wasn't continuous? Could it still be differentiable? And how would I determine if the function was differentiable then?

Comment: You should take $x\to1^{\pm}$, not $x\to0^{\pm}$.

Comment: Have you written this correctly?  The point in question is x = 1, not x = 0.  And the function is discontinuous at x = 1.

Comment: Ugh, meant 1 but when I copied over the formulas I forgot to change it. Yes, it's 1, and the results are for 1.

Comment: But as x approaches 1 from the right the derivative is 4.

Comment: Did you mean $x^2 - 2x + 1$?

Comment: Yes, it's -2x, I edited it when I saw the error.

Comment: Got it.  With those changes made, your conclusion is correct.  The function is continuous at x = 1 (and everywhere else) but not differentiable at x =1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is not differentiable and if you draw it you will see an elbow (not smooth). It cannot be differentiable without being continuous because the theorem you are referring to presumes continuity at the point.

Comment: What about integrability? What conditions should I check for it to me integrable?

Comment: @MikhaelM I think that is much different topic, deserving a separate question.

Comment: Yup, I thought it was something trivial but after a bit of research I see that it isn't. I made a new question for that.